# Unable to verify the first certificate - IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I installed iconic and for that, I first did **npm config set strict-SSL false** and then when I created an ionic app using **ionic start myApp tabs**.
This error showed up

> Error: unable to verify the first certificate

```
at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1060:34)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:639:8)strong text
```

Comment: It looks like you may be running into proxy issues. Do you know if your computer connects to the internet through a proxy?

Comment: No My computer is not connected through proxy.

Comment: see https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-unable-to-verify-the-first-certificate/42968